# Backgroundworker doesn't like Clipboard

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, backgroundworker, clipboard

Example full code:

```
Private Sub test()
    Clipboard.SetDataObject("test") '<- gives error
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    test()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

The error I get is:

```
{"Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it."}
```

I have tried using

```
BeginInvoke(New Action(Function() Clipboard.SetDataObject(strText.ToString)))
```

instead of

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(strText.ToString)))
```

But get a message saying that the expression does not produce on value.

Comment: Just remove ".Dispatcher" to use the form's BeginInvoke method.

Comment: @HansPassant, that fixed the `Dispatcher` error, but now clipboard is giving me an error saying `Expression does not produce a value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the part when you want to make the copy, try:

```
Private Thr As Threading.Thread
Thr = New Threading.Thread(New Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf NewThread))
Thr.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
Thr.Start()
```

and Define:

```
 Private Sub NewThread()
      Try
           Clipboard.SetDataObject(strText.ToString)

      Catch ex As Exception
           ' Log exception
      End Try
 End Sub
```

Comment: Converting the `private void NewThread()` to vb.net is not as issue, however, I can't see to convert the first part `Thread newThread = new Thread(NewThread);`